# Change netmask in openvpn

Tags: openvpn, linux-networking

I have an openvpn with netmask /27 but I need more addrrsses for clients, the question is how can I do it? Can I change netmask on my openvpn server config to /26 or I have to rebuild openvpn server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to rebuild just update the config and restart the service/host-server.
For reference: https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/how-to-change-vpn-netmask.39091/